# Error End of input at line 1 column 1 path $ Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to upload data on server as well as audio file but i am getting the same error from last two days

**here is my Interface**

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("index.php")
  Call<Result> uploadFile(@Part("client_phone") String phn,
                          @Part("call_type") String Ststus,
                          @Part("start_time") String Stime,
                          @Part("end_time")  String Etime,
                          @Part MultipartBody.Part body,
                          @Part("employe_phone") String emphn);
```

**And Here is My Retrofit Class**

```
private static final String ROOT_URL ="http://192.168.0.113/recorder/api/";


public RetroClient() {

}

/**
 * Get Retro Client
 *
 * @return JSON Object
 */



private static Retrofit getRetroClient() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();


}

public static ApiService getApiService() {
    return getRetroClient().create(ApiService.class);
}
```

And Here is the call to API

```
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    MultipartBody.Part body =
        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploaded_file", file.getName(), requestFile);

    Misscall ms=new Misscall("7276367824","IN","2016-12-12_12:12:12","2016-12-12_12:13:03","7276367824");
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    String json=gson.toJson(ms);
    Log.i(MyApp.TAG, "Object Json"+ms);

  //Call<Result> resultCall = service.uploadFile(map,body);
  Call<Result> resultCall = service.uploadFile("7276367824","IN","123456","1234567",body,"7276367824");
```

**Please help me**
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was happening only on the emulator (not all the time just in some cases). For some reason sometimes something was happening and the response that the server provides me came without its last char e.g. "}" and this caused the error. I don't know if this was caused by retrofit or something else. Could not reproduce it on real device tough.